# What happens if I draw animate beings unintentionally or not knowing in is a sin?

Tags: halal-haram, drawing

Assalammualaikum, brothers and sisters,

So I used to draw living beings without knowing it is a bad thing in Islam. I wanted to know what to do with the drawings and any punishment/curse for doing so. If there is a punishment/curse, what should I do?

I much appreciate if you answer me!

Answer (score 1):

Asalaam Alaikum

in islam every action is based upon it's intention. the consequence of the action is in accordance with the intention. there is no harm on you if you did something without knowing if it was a sin but we must also remember that ignorance is not an excuse for sinning. i will try to clarify in the light of authentic sunnah and quran,insha Allah.

*Narrated 'Umar bin Al-Khattab:
I heard Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) saying, "The reward of deeds depends upon the intentions and every person will get the reward according to what he has intended. So whoever emigrated for worldly benefits or for a woman to marry, his emigration was for what he emigrated for." [bukhari]*

this hadith establishes the fact that what we intend is what matters. intentions itself are rewarded.

let us remind ourselves of these following verses from the quran just for a better understandind, insha Allah.

**The repentance accepted by Allah is only for those who do wrong in ignorance [or carelessness] and then repent soon after. It is those to whom Allah will turn in forgiveness, and Allah is ever Knowing and Wise.[chapter 4 verse 17]**

and

**Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah. Indeed, Allah forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful."[chapter 39 verse 53]**

it is incumbent upon you that as soon as you know it is a sin, to turn back to Allah and ask for fogiveness and insha Allah, you will be forgiven.

may Allah the mighty and sublime grant us mercy and guide us to the straight path.

Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

It is Haram to imitate the creations of Allah, for Allah is the ONE and TRUE Creator in the Universe. However, doing so is permitted for permissable reasons such as Education etc. ..

It is best to destroy the drawings and ask Allah for forgiveness, for HE is the most merciful and most beneficent.

Answer (score 0):

The topic of drawing living beings is one with varying valid opinions.

**Drawing Living things is Haram**

One opinion is drawing anything living is haram.

**Drawing Living things is Makrooh (disliked)**

Another opinion is that drawing anything living is only makruh (disliked) which is what the Maliki Fiqh believes in:

- [The Maliki View on Pictures of Humans and Animals](https://islamqa.org/maliki/seekersguidance-maliki/85229/the-maliki-view-on-pictures-of-humans-and-animals/)
- [The Maliki View on Pictures of Humans and Animals (SeekersGuidance)](https://seekersguidance.org/answers/maliki-fiqh/the-maliki-view-on-pictures-of-humans-and-animals/)

**Drawing Living thing is Mubah (permissible)**

Other scholars considered the drawing of living things to be permissible as long as the drawing isn't something haram, promoting haram, or meant to be used for haram (such as worshipping, etc).

Sheikh Yusuf Al-Qaradawi's fatwa in Arabic regarding the drawing of living things being permissible: [Yusuf Al-Qaradawi's Fatwa (Arabic)](https://hawramani.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/fatwa_drawing.pdf)

Assembly of Muslim Jurists of America, Scholar Dr. Main Khalid Al-Qudah:
[Drawing Living, Animate Objects](https://www.amjaonline.org/fatwa/en/21678/drawing-living-animate-objects)

Comment: It would be better to quote the crux of the scholar's stance/viewpoint/fatwa in your answer rather than just attaching links.